# Why the random numbers generated are different even though the seed is same?

Tags: c++

The random numbers are being generated at the same moment i.e. same time.Therefore the seed should be same and is same.But why the random numbers generated are different even though the conditions are same.

```
# include < cstdlib > 
# include < iostream > 
#include < ctime >
using namespace std;
int main()
        {
        double a,b;

    srand(time(0));
    a = rand()% (1000 + 1 - 200) + 200;   
    cout << "Seed = " << time(0) << endl;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    b = rand()% (1000 + 1 - 200) + 200;  
    cout << "Seed = " << time(0) << endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected
First number =
529
Second number =
529

Actual results
First number =
529
Second number =
819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PRNGs produce a sequence of numbers by keeping state. That, coupled with the algorithm the PRNG uses, fully determines the number an invocation will produce. As such the state also has to change when the PRNG is invoked, otherwise it will produce the exact same number at every invocation.

You seed **once** and then call the PRNG. This modifies its internal state and returns a number. The next call will not operate on the same state, so it may produce a different number. And it does in your example

Seeding is how you determine the state a PRNG starts from. If you were to add another call to `srand(time(0))` before calling `rand` a second time, it may with great likelihood return the previous number, because as you correctly noted `time` may not have had a chance to update. This is why the common advice is to seed only once per program in such a fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo random number generators do generate a sequence of pseudo random numbers. At some point the sequence will repeat (after very long time for a good prng). With the seed you just choose where you start the sequence. Hence for the same seed you will always get the same sequence, but typically you will not get a sequence of all identical numbers. Calling `rand` will always get you the next number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Your seed is always different, since you call `srand` with `time(0)`. Even though you pass `0` it still returns time, which will always be different for different calls.

You can see it from documentation for `time`

> `time_t time (time_t* timer);`
>
> Get current time Get the current calendar
>   time as a value of type `time_t`.
>
> The function returns this value, and if the argument is not a null
>   pointer, it also sets this value to the object pointed by timer.

If you want your seed to be the same, just make it a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeding the RNG here:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Then you are getting a random numbr from it here:

```
a = rand()% (1000 + 1 - 200) + 200;
```

And another random number here:

```
b = rand()% (1000 + 1 - 200) + 200;
```

Nothing else has an impact on the result that you're getting. Printing `time(0)` won't change the result. You could, however, put another `srand(time(0));` before the `b = rand()%`, then you will most likely get the same result twice (assuming that the time was still the same in both cases, but you'll see that when you print the time).

Answer (score 0):

> Why the random numbers generated are different even though the seed is
>   the same.

Your statement is incorrect ... the seed your code is providing to srand is different for each second.

---

In C++, the integer literal 0 (when used as an actual parameter to a function with a pointer parameter) is treated the same as the nullptr.  This is a C++ requirement for portability of your code to those (unusual) computers where a nullptr is not 0x0.

The declaration

```
std::time_t time( std::time_t* arg );
```

shows arg is a pointer to a struct.

In the invocation of

```
std::time_t time(0);
```

the C++ language will change the 0 to the value a nullptr appropriate for your hardware.

Thus, time(nullptr) returns a different result each second.   (But the same result when quickly invoked more than once in a given wall-clock-second.)

Thus

```
srand(time(0));
```

will produce a different sequence starting value for each wall-clock-second.